# Lognormal distribution properties (product of lognormals is lognormal but with what mean and variance?) Wikipedia has this wrong?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, normalization, normality-assumption, lognormal-distribution

I'm trying to understand under which circumstances the product of variables that are lognormally distributed is lognormally distributed (and most imporantly, with what mean and variance).

I tried Wikipedia but feel there is an inconsistency. Why would the third bullet point be any different than the last bullet point? Shouldn't the last bullet point have variance $a \sigma^2$ instead of the one it shows ($a^2 \sigma^2$)? Or vice-versa?

[image: Wikipedia screenshot]

Comment: Did you notice that one bullet concerns a *product* while the other concerns a *sum*?

Comment: Thanks! Will edit that part! But my question between the two circled distributions still remains

Comment: Study the properties of variances: Wikipedia is correct.

Comment: Please note also that these parameters are not the mean and variance of the lognormal (but of the underlying normal).

Comment: What I don't understand is why arent the two circled the same? The only difference is that the first allows $\mu_j$ and $\sigma_j^2$ to vary by observation whereas the second has the same for all observations. Why would the means look the same but the variances differently?

Comment: The difference that in the last case you only have 1 draw of X and then you raise it to the power of a and in the fist case you have n draws of X, right?

Comment: That is correct. If $a$ is an integer, you can think of the first case as a product of $a$ independent random variables but the second case is a product of $a$ perfectly correlated random variables which is why the variance is larger.